# Qual é o significado de um arquivo "Manifest" em programação?

Tags: terminologia

Creio que já tenho visto um arquivo chamado *manifest* relacionado a algumas bibliotecas de certas linguagens de programação. Se me lembro bem, existe um *manifest* no Android Studio.

Lembro também de ter visto um arquivo chamado `manifest.json` no framework de PHP chamado Laravel (isso ocorre especificamente quando geramos minificações e unificações ou versionamentos de arquivos JavaScript ou CSS).

A mesma coisa existe também no [Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest), onde creio estar relacionado as extensões instaladas.

Como parece ser uma coisa comum entre bibliotecas de diversos tipos, eu gostaria de entender qual é a finalidade desses arquivos *manifest*.

Pelo que entendi ele tem finalidade de "listar" algum recurso que vão ser utilizados, mas talvez o sentido seja um pouco mais amplo.

Sendo assim gostaria de saber: Qual é a finalidade de um arquivo *manifest*?

Comment: A ideia do manifest é ser alguma coisa que responde a seguinte pergunta para o sistema operacional, máquina virtual ou ambiente de execução pertinente: "*O que é esse troço, para que ele serve e como é que eu executo isso?*"

Comment: Essa é uma das perguntas de terminologia mais interessantes que eu vi até agora aqui no site. Queria entender o voto negativo.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida tem acontecido constantemente. Deve ser alguém com raiva de mim. Mas é melhor ignorar

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Ah, certo. É que eu já havia notado uma tendência das questões de terminologia de não serem bem aceitas, então pensei que era algo contra o tema. Tem razão, bola pra frente.

Comment: Na verdade, se o problema realmente é com as perguntas que eu faço, não apareceu ainda ninguém que apontasse qual é o problema, preferiu ficar no anonimato.

Comment: Mas será bem-vindo. A minha intensão é agregar conteúdo ao site com minhas perguntas. Se puderem indicar o que a pergunta pode melhorar, será bem-vindo. Eu não sou perfeito! Sugestões são bem-vindas, sempre!

Comment: Vale lembrar que as perguntas podem ser editadas por qualquer um. Se for alguma picuinha com o modo de escrever, os termos usados, a formatação etc., é só sugerir uma mudança.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Acho que seu comentário deveria estar como resposta, claro que com alguns detalhes a mais, mas a ideia do exemplo ficou muito boa.

Comment: @jbueno Até pensei em colocar como resposta, mas achei curto demais e por isso só coloquei em comentário. Ainda mais sabendo que em pouco tempo alguém (no caso o bigown) iria aparecer para dar uma resposta mais completa. Entretanto, se eu pensar em algo importante que não foi abordado na resposta dele, eu posto uma outra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normalmente é um arquivo com dados básicos sobre uma aplicação que ajudam a plataforma executar de forma apropriada. Para cada plataforma pode ter alguma especificidade, mas o básico é ter o nome, versão, arquivos que fazem parte da aplicação ou que devem ter alguma ação específica, alguma configuração de como se comportar, eventualmente alguma assinatura digital, etc.

De fato no contexto do Google Chrome ele é [usado pelas extensões](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest).

Exemplo pego da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <!--I am okay with whatever security privilege level-->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <!--I need Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Runtime to run-->
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC90.CRT' version='9.0.21022.8' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Hum... Interessante. No caso do Laravel Elixir, como ele trabalha com arquivos de assets, ele gera uma espécie de "apontamento" para a aplicação saber qual arquivo unificado/compactado é oriundo de outro.

Comment: É isso, cada coisa tem um jeito de usar. É um metadado.

Answer (score 9):

Trivia: O termo se origina da prática náutica, onde o [manifesto de carga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_(transportation)) lista todos os itens (carga ou pessoal) expedidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> [Manifesto de passageiros do SS La Touraine (EUA), outubro de 1913, pgs. 204–05](https://www.flickr.com/photos/volturnohistory/6100726756), por [Andrew Baker](https://www.flickr.com/photos/volturnohistory/) - CC 2.0

Um [arquivo manifest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file), em computação, é um arquivo que contém metadados para um grupo de arquivos que fazem parte de um conjunto ou unidade coerente.

Por exemplo, os arquivos de um programa de computador pode ter um manifesto descrevendo o *nome*, *número da versão* e os *arquivos* que constituem do programa.

Várias linguagens e plataformas utilizam arquivos *manifest*. Segue abaixo uma lista (não-exaustiva):

- Java: [manifest.mf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767886/use-of-the-manifest-mf-file-in-java) utilizado para criação de pacotes JAR;
- Windows: [manifest.xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj151528.aspx)  é utilizado para descrever tanto conteúdo quanto como mapeamentos de estrutura de diretório;
- Android: [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) possui informações essenciais à execução do programa, como permissões ou capacidades necessárias;
- NPM: [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) descreve, entre outras coisas, arquivos e dependências;
- HTML5: o elemento `<html>` pode possuir uma propriedade, [`manifest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache), que provê *caching* de conteúdo com o objetivo de permitir a aplicações web serem executadas em modo *off-line*.

Comment: composer.json é um manifest do composer então :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters se ele declara conteúdo e/ou informações a respeito do programa, sim, ele é um manifest.